# Why does this subclass have to implement a final method?

Tags: scala

I thought putting final in `Function` would stop this issue from happening? I'm not too familiar with Scala. Can someone explain?

`Class 'Country must either be declared abstract or implement abstract member 'execute():Object' in path.to.Invokable'`

```
class Country extends MarketFunction("america") {}
```

```
abstract class MarketFunction(function: String) extends Function {
...
}
```

```
trait Function extends Invokable {
  final def execute(): AnyRef = {
    // not important
  }
}
```

```
public interface Invokable {
  Object execute();
}
```

Is it because `AnyRef` is not a direct comparison to java `Object`?

Comment: Try adding `override` into the `execute` of `Function`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez `override final def execute()` results in `Method 'execute' overrides nothing` in `Function`

Comment: You have your answer there, when that error disappears the other will too. - Try with `Any` instead.

Comment: If you suspect AnyRef might not be the same with java Object, why not try with java Object?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
class Country extends MarketFunction("america") {}
```

```
abstract class MarketFunction(function: String) extends Function[AnyRef] {
...
}
```

```
trait Function[A <: AnyRef] extends Invokable {
  override final def execute(): A = {
    // not important
  }
}
```

```
public interface Invokable {
  Object execute();
}
```